# Cakephp Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end during form submit

Tags: cakephp

I need some help on cakephp validation error. 
I created register form with model validation multiple rule. 
This form work with validation on localhost is good but on online get a error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end
>   lib/Cake/Utility/Validation.php on line 140

I am unable to finding error what happen ?

Comment: Add your model and controller code

Answer (score 1):

### It's a parse error

In a file in CakePHP. As such none of your application code is relevant to the problem.

[Validation.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Validation.php#L1015) is a thousand lines long, the error says it reached the end of the file at line 140. so: It has been modified/truncated. To fix the problem **ensure** that your Cake folder contains an unmodified copy of [whichever release](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases) you are using.

Comment: Please accept an answer, a comment doesn't make stack overflow treat the question as resolved.